# Design Suggestion For Enum

Tags: java

I have a legacy application which is being migrated into microservices. As of now, the Database is shared.

We have a table in which categories are stored. For ex: User Roles categories, User status categories (active / inactive) etc. 
The problem is the table's primary key which is a sequence is what used across all other tables for reference. 
Sometimes, I need to provide the id for an enum value / find the enum value based on the given id.

```
public enum UserRole implements Domain {

    GUEST ("Guest"),
    ADMIN ("Admin");

    private static final Map<String, BillingMode> BY_CODE = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<Long, BillingMode> BY_ID = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        Arrays.stream(values())
                .forEach(ur -> BY_CODE.put(ur.getCode(), ur));
    }

    private long id;
    private String code;

    UserRole(String code){
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
        BY_ID.put(id, this);
    }

    public static UserRole fromCode(String code){
        return BY_CODE.get(code);
    }

    public static UserRole fromId(long id){
        return BY_ID.get(id);
    }

}
```

Currently I load the enum with code and id during start up. Is this really a good design? I some how do not like this implementation. I am not getting any other ideas as well. I also have 20 different categories (20 enums). I do not want to repeat the code.

---

The code value like 'Guest' is same for all the environments. But the corresponding id is different for each environment like dev, qa, stg and prod. This is what made me add the setters to the enum.

Comment: Can you give an excerpt from one of the tables? I don't really get why you do what you do

Comment: Enums should ideally be constant, not have setters

Comment: Yes, the idea that an Enum contains mutable state is very dubious. Remember for example that when you serialize enum instances, such state will be lost.

Comment: @cricket_007, you are right. The code value like 'Guest' is same for all the environments. But the corresponding id is different for each environment like dev, qa, stg and prod. This is what made me add the setters to the enum.

Comment: Why don't you just have a separate map for the id->constant, not part of the enum itself? In each environment you load that map whenever you need it. There is no need to keep it inside the enum - it's a function of the environment in which you are running, not something inherent in the constant itself.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, Ok, I really appreciate it. I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

The references should not be by id but by code.

And certainly should there be hard coded id constants are used (check that).

That simplifies many queries, removing joins to the final enum table.

One might even think of SQL column enums instead of references.

The enum table becomes useless. The enum class itself not.

That is a *simplifying* redesign that brings a measurable improvement.
It can be done incrementally.

The requirement is that the domain is *closed*, the domain values are *fixed* (hence an enum).

Should you still want to have enum classes: **do not use an enum,** but your own entity.
Then you can use a normal db table repository, have a list of all values. You might suffer some hard-coded constants: `@UserInRole("Admin") ...` but you can add and drop values.